# Multiple javascript(different version) conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict, esri

I've some problem using 2 APIs together, OneMap API and ESRI(Arcgis) API.

My problem here is that I want to use OneMap API, which is based on ESRI(Arcgis) API but there are a few missing functionality in OneMap's API that I needed to complete my task, for e.g `featureLayer`. This `featureLayer` which is found in ESRI(Arcgis) API is what I needed and I've tried to include both API, to call the `featureLayer`, but there will be errors and the map will not show. I guess that could be a conflict as I could use the APIs seperately.

The reason why I chose to use OneMap is because its focused on Singapore and more detailed/updated information on the map as compared to ESRI's map.

So is there a way to prevent this conflict when using the 2 API I've mentioned above? or is there anyway to specify when to use which either API when needed by the function?

**EDIT:**
Here are the error message,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dojo' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_loadPath'
```

Comment: So have you tried using jQuery in noConflict mode? Did it help? Are you even asking about jQuery or about these other libraries? What sort of errors, exactly and precisely? Make it easy to help.

Comment: Sorry, have edited my question. I am asking about the OneMap API and ESRI(Arcgis) API. The error im facing now is that when the 2 API are being used together, my map wont run.

Comment: Them not working is indeed an error but what KIND of error? Be very specific... open your console and copy paste the errors. It's impossible to guess what the errors might be.

Comment: My bad, I've added the error msg~

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error messages, one of your libraries appears to require the Dojo library. You should try including it, before including the other two libraries.

Once it is included ahead of the other libraries you should see those error messages disappear.

Your code itself, which will create the map, needs to be included in the Dojo domReady plugin:

```
  <script>
    require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) { 
      // code to create the map and add a basemap will go here 
    });
  </script>
```

I don't know anything specific about any of these libraries but it seems like this should at least get you past those errors (and possibly onto some new ones but we can deal with those when they occur).

Based on an example from the ArcGIS site it seems like Dojo, or some portion of it, may be included already. Check out this where they include the library and then load up the map on dom ready (you would also need to include map styles and create an HTML element to hold the map (in this case a div with the ID of "mapDiv":

```
 <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/"></script>
  <script>
    var map;
    require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
      map = new Map("mapDiv", {
        center: [-56.049, 38.485],
        zoom: 3,
        basemap: "streets"
      });
    });
  </script>
```